# Measuring width of text issue

Tags: android, textview, paint

I'm calculating width of text depending on display's width.I converted display size from pixel(240x320) to dp(320x426).It is clear that measurement of text by Paint class gives results in dp.When I measure three words by given below method it's result is more than 320 , but TextView displays these words at one line also with some little extra space???

```
private int calcWidthSize(CharSequence cha, int currentSize) {
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
        paint.setTextSize(currentSize);
        return (int) Math.ceil(paint.measureText(cha, 0, cha.length()));
 }
```

I tried with another Paint method, but still problem is not solved:

```
private int calculateWidthSize(CharSequence cha, int currentSize) {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
        paint.setTextSize(currentSize);
        paint.getTextBounds(cha.toString(), 0, cha.length(), bounds);
        return (int) Math.ceil(bounds.width());
 }
```

Maybe it is TextView's fault?
My goal is by measuring text width and height, I should get how much text fits for one page in a textview(display size).Any help please.

Comment: Actually, how to solve this problem? or is this android issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some changes on my code I finally got solution:

```
private float calcWidthSize(CharSequence cha, float currentSize) {
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
        paint.setTextSize(currentSize);
        return  paint.measureText(cha, 0, cha.length());
 }
```

currentSize was setting directly before,then I gave currentSize parameter by getting textSize from TextView, `currentSize=tv.getTextSize();` Also I did not convert display width **to dp**.Now it returns result in *pixels* format.Hope it helps someone...